# How to find last item in a .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following but I get

> (index):58 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.last is not a function

```
var myId; 
 jQuery.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eilimit=500&eititle=Template:Infobox&callback=?", {
    disablelimitreport: true,
    format: "json"
  }, function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data.query.embeddedin, function(i, item) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this[0] === jQuery.last()[0]) {
       var myId = item.pageid;
    }
    console.log(myId);
    });
  });
```

[JsFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/309/)  see console

Comment: reference the last item in the array, there is no last() method

Comment: @epascarello could you elaborate it more please? Going a bit crazy on it

Comment: if (i===data.query.embeddedin.length-1)

Comment: @UmarZaii see console here https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/309/

Comment: @epascarello that works, put that into an answer and I will accept it as you have been the first to answer. Thanks

Comment: Unless this is just a basic example, the loop is uneccessary, you can get the last item from the array in any number of ways without iterating.

Comment: @adeneo like how? I am looking for the latest item.pageid

Comment: Assuming it's an array, `data.query.embeddedin.pop().pageid`, note that it modifies the array

Comment: Or `data.query.embeddedin[data.query.embeddedin.length - 1].pageid` if you don't want to modify the array.  (edited to correct the off-by-one error)

Comment: @DanielBeck - arrays are zero-based, subtract `1` from the length

Comment: Yup, you're right, thanks @adeneo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the length of the element and move the index back.. Try this one. Hope will work in you.

```
var myId; 
jQuery.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&list=embeddedin&eilimit=500&eititle=Template:Infobox&callback=?", {
   disablelimitreport: true,
   format: "json"
}, function(data) {
  jQuery.each(data.query.embeddedin, function(index, item) { 
     var length = data.query.embeddedin.length;
     if (index === (length - 1)) {
       var myId = item.pageid;
       console.log('The last pageid is : ' + myId);
     } 
  });
});
```

Comment: does this provide me with the last `item.pageid; ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to test the first variable in the each function to the length of the array (but remember that the iterator is zero-based which needs one subtracted from the length):

```
if( i === (data.query.embeddedin.length -1) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the last element, there's no need to do a `.each` over the whole array.

Everything you have after retrieving the data could be replaced by the single line:

```
var myId = data.query.embeddedin[data.query.embeddedin.length - 1].pageid
```

Demonstration:

```js
var myId;
jQuery.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eilimit=500&eititle=Template:Infobox&callback=?", {
  disablelimitreport: true,
  format: "json"
}, function(data) {
  myId = data.query.embeddedin[data.query.embeddedin.length - 1].pageid
  console.log(myId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```